# udp sending packet failling

Tags: java, android

I'm try to send a message through a udp connection but it fails at

```
 socket.send(packet);
```

here is how I set up the server and send the packet

```
                InetAddress iadd=InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP); 
                DatagramSocket socket=new DatagramSocket(); 
                byte[] buff="AAHHHH it worked".getBytes(); 
                DatagramPacket packet=new  DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length); 
                socket.send(packet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you've pasted, you don't appear to ever be associating your InetAddress with your DatagramSocket.

Try: `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(portNumber, iadd);` to specify the address and port of where the datagrams should be going.

Your client should be listening on the same port on the other end.